# does array elements need to be volatile? if so, how can I make it?

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility, atomic

Suppose I have little code like this:

```
public class Test {
    final Data[] dataArray;
    final int maxSize;
    volatile long nextWriteNo;
    volatile long nextReadNo;

    public Test(int maxSize){
        this.dataArray = new Data[maxSize];
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.nextWriteNo = 0L;
        this.nextReadNo = 0L;
    }

    public void write(Data data){
        synchronized (this) {
            dataArray[(int)(nextWriteNo & (maxSize - 1))] = data;
            nextWriteNo = nextWriteNo + 1L;
        }
    }

    public Data read(Data data){
        synchronized (this) {
            Data data = dataArray[(int)(nextReadNo & (maxSize -1))];
            nextReadNo= nextReadNo + 1L;
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Where one thread will call `write()` method multiple times, and other thread will call `read()` method multiple times. `write()` method updates array, while read method reads array. All happens inside `synchronized` block. So for visibility, or happens before relationships, does array elements (object references) need to be `volatile`? If so, how can I make it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to use `volatile` inside of a synchronization block. The block itself guarantees the value's state to be consistent between reads and writes.

Comment: just small addition: synchronize block means that all changes to "this threads memory" will be visible for all other threads after block done

Comment: I am asking about thread caching. Will update made to array elements from one thread, be visible to other thread instantly without needing to make it volatile?

Comment: Yes, the references themselves will be visible to other threads without being volatile. But not the state of the instance of the reference. Any updates there would need to be synchronized separately.

Comment: Sorry, not much clear :(. Suppose call to write() changes value in 0th element from null to object reference, will this object reference immediately visible to other thread on calling read()? or other thread MAY see null still?

Comment: *"But not the state of the instance of the reference."* I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. `synchronized` guarantees consistency of all state that gets touched inside it. I think your answer text is exactly fine. There is no reason to use volatile with correct synchronization.

Comment: @UDPLover You should read this answer again. ; ) All state is guaranteed by `synchronized`.

Comment: @Radiodef My poor wording, I think. I was trying to respond to UDPLover's comment about array elements being updated being visible to other threads. I answer yes, but want to make sure to explain that, in his synchronized block, he is not changing the state of the Object held by the array reference, only the reference itself. Any later changes (outside of the block) to the object's state would need to be synchronized or made volatile. I may be misconstruing what he is asking, however.

Comment: @Radiodef ok, but answer is bit looks like written in hurry :( Bacause I have never used volatile local variables inside synchronized block.

Comment: @UDPLover Please explain which part is confusing. I can try to clarify. But first, please make sure you understand the terminology being used (what is `volatile`, what does `synchronized` mean). I think once you're clear on those, the answer is self-evident.

Comment: @Kon I understood that volatile is used to make variable read/write atomic, and changes made to it will be visible to all threads (no caching by threads). And synchronized is used to prevent threads from executing block of code simultaneously. What I am confused is, will changing array element by one thread inside synchronized be visible to directly to other thread (array element values wont be cached?) without being it volatile?

Comment: @Kon in nutshell, will variables (without being declared volatile explicitely) be always volatile if it is accessed or changed from synchronized block? if so, making nextWriteNo and nextReadNo volatile in my code meaningless?

Comment: @UDPLover: to be more precise, its not like all variables are `volatile`, but for all threads using `synchronized` on the same object, all values will be visible as intended. Given your code as is, i.e. both methods are using `synchronized` correctly, there is no need to declare any variable as  `volatile`.